# How to split a DataFrame Column into Four parts using two different delimiters

Tags: python, dataframe, split, csv

I am working on a project that will take our old database system queries and map them to the new database system queries.  I want to be able to read the FROM statements, split them into Database, Schema, Table, and Alias.  The data looks like this:

```
FROM DatabaseA.SchemaA.Table1 tbl 
    INNER JOIN DatabaseB.SchemaC.Table13 tbl13 
         ON tbl.column12 = tbl.column12
```

I have created a dataframe from the full SQL query and extracted just the FROM statement into a new dataframe (I'm using two different functions):

```
# Reads file - creates dataframe
def readSQL(file_path):
    # convert to a string
    file_path=file_path.decode("utf-8")
    
    # Set sql_script as a global variable
    # Once sql_script is populated it can
    # be called from other functions
    global sql_script
    
    # Open file
    # Separate every line
    df = open(file_path,'r')
    lines = df.readlines()
    df.close()
    # print(lines)
    
    # Create the dataframe
    sql_script = pd.DataFrame(columns=('StatementDSC','ColumnTable'))
    i = 0
    StatementDSC = ""
    ColumnTable = ""

    for line in lines:
        if ('SELECT' in line) or ('FROM' in line) or ('WHERE' in line):
            StatementDSC = line.strip() # remove \n
        else: #(',' in line) or ('.' in line):
            ColumnTable = line.strip() # remove \t and /n
    
        # Create next line
        sql_script.loc[i] = [StatementDSC,ColumnTable]
        i = i + 1
        
    return sql_script

    # print(sql_script)
    
# Reads FROM Statement breaks down tables/aliases/joins
def readFROM(full_SQL):
    # Create FROM Dataframe
    df = full_SQL.loc[full_SQL['StatementDSC']== 'FROM']
    
    # Drop empty rows
   # df.drop(df.ColumnTable == "",axis=0)
    print(df)
    
    # split ColumnTable by periods
    # Create new Columns: 
        # Database, Schema, Table
    split_data = df["ColumnTable"].str.split('.')
    data = split_data.to_list()
    names = ["Database","Schema","TableAlias"]
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=names)
    print(new_df)
```

I can get the data to split from this:

```
     StatementDSC              ColumnTable
5         FROM                                                   
6         FROM                PPDAC.PLAN.DOCTORS Docs
7         FROM  INNER JOIN PPDAC.PLAN.DOCTORSINFO DocInfo
8         FROM                    ON Docs.DocID = DocInfo.DocID
```

To this:

```
    Database              Schema           TableAlias
0                         None             None
1  PPDAC                  PLAN             DOCTORS Docs
2  INNER JOIN PPDAC     PLAN             DOCTORSINFO DocInfo
```

How do I add another delimiter to separate these into four by using both a period and a space?

I've seen other answers, but they've been for one line and not repeating on multiple lines.

Comment: How did you get row 2? I don't see "CLARITY" anywhere in your original `df`?

Comment: My mistake - I was removing our proprietary names and missed that.  I'll fix it.

Comment: So if your first dataframe is `df`, don't you just need `df["ColumnTable"].str.split(".", expand=True)`?

Comment: I could probably change that, but that's not my question.  I need to know how to separate with multiple delimiters.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm telling you. You first separate with one. And then with the other.

Comment: No, because it still won't split the table name from the Alias, which is what I want.  It will return three columns and I want four columns.

Comment: After getting your df with three columns, you can just do `df["TableAlias"].str.split(" ", expand=True)`?

Comment: Yes, I know that, but I want to do the split once.  Are you telling me that it can't be done?

Comment: Yup. `pandas.str.split` takes one delimeter only. See the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)

Comment: And, there's no other way but str.split to separate columns?  Nothing else to suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex to split based on multiple delimiters, such as any delimiter in the [ brackets ], in this case . or space.  See this toy example:

```
row1list = ['1.2.3 4']
row2list = ['1.4.5 6']
row3list = ['2.7.8 9']
df = pd.DataFrame([row1list, row2list, row3list], columns=['ColumnTable'])

df2 = df['ColumnTable'].str.split('[ .]', expand=True)
print(df2)
#    0  1  2  3
# 0  1  2  3  4
# 1  1  4  5  6
# 2  2  7  8  9
```

Comment: This is wonderful!  It is a big help and it worked!  Thanks!